# How to clean and split HTML tags in R?

Tags: html, r, split

My parser create a data frame, which looks like:

```
    name          html
 1  John         <span class="incident-icon" data-minute="68" data-second="37" data-id="8028"></span><span class="name-meta-data">68</span>
 2 Steve         <span class="incident-icon" data-minute="69" data-second="4" data-id="132205"></span><span class="name-meta-data">69</span>
```

So how I can extract usefull information from HTML? For example, I want to use some HTML attributes as features:

```
   name minute second     id
1  John     68     37   8028
2 Steve     69      4 132205
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the data frame in your question, you can try the following. Your data frame is called `mydf` here. You can extract all numbers with `stri_extract_all_regex()`. Then, you follow the classic method converting a list to a data frame. Then, you assign new column names and bind the result with the column, `name` in the original data frame.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

stri_extract_all_regex(str = mydf$url, pattern = "[0-9]+") %>%
unlist %>%
matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = T) %>%
data.frame %>%
setNames(c("minute", "second", "ID", "data")) %>%
bind_cols(mydf["name"], .)

#   name minute second     ID data
#1  John     68     37   8028   68
#2 Steve     69      4 132205   69
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Steve"), url = c("<span class=\"incident-icon\" data-minute=\"68\" data-second=\"37\" data-id=\"8028\"></span><span class=\"name-meta-data\">68</span>", 
"<span class=\"incident-icon\" data-minute=\"69\" data-second=\"4\" data-id=\"132205\"></span><span class=\"name-meta-data\">69</span>"
)), .Names = c("name", "url"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

regex is possible, but I prefer the `rvest` package for this,

this is easier with data.table or dplyr, but lets do it base R, (on the off-chance that those are new concepts)

```
# Example data

df <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Steve"), html = c("<span class=\"incident-icon\" data-minute=\"68\" data-second=\"37\" data-id=\"8028\"></span><span class=\"name-meta-data\">68</span>", 
"<span class=\"incident-icon\" data-minute=\"69\" data-second=\"4\" data-id=\"132205\"></span><span class=\"name-meta-data\">69</span>"
)), .Names = c("name", "html"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

rvest lets us split this up using the DOM, which can be a lot nicer than working with regex for the same thing.

```
library(rvest)

# Get span attributes from each row:
spanattrs <- 
    lapply(df$html, 
           function(y) read_html(y) %>% html_node('span') %>% html_attrs)

# rbind to get a data.frame with all attributes
final <- data.frame(df, do.call(rbind,spanattrs))

> final
   name                                                                                                                        html         class
1  John  <span class="incident-icon" data-minute="68" data-second="37" data-id="8028"></span><span class="name-meta-data">68</span> incident-icon
2 Steve <span class="incident-icon" data-minute="69" data-second="4" data-id="132205"></span><span class="name-meta-data">69</span> incident-icon
  data.minute data.second data.id
1          68          37    8028
2          69           4  132205
```

Lets remove the html so it's a little nicer in the viewer here:

```
> final$html <- NULL
> final
   name         class data.minute data.second data.id
1  John incident-icon          68          37    8028
2 Steve incident-icon          69           4  132205
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate `rvest` approach using `purrr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, sep=",", text='name,html
John,<span class="incident-icon" data-minute="68" data-second="37" data-id="8028"></span><span class="name-meta-data">68</span>
Steve,<span class="incident-icon" data-minute="69" data-second="4" data-id="132205"></span><span class="name-meta-data">69</span>')

by_row(df, .collate="cols", 
       ~read_html(.$html) %>% 
         html_nodes("span:first-of-type") %>% 
         html_attrs() %>% 
         flatten_chr() %>% 
         as.list() %>% 
         flatten_df()) %>% 
  select(-html, -class1) %>% 
  setNames(gsub("^data-|1$", "", colnames(.)))
## # A tibble: 2 × 4
##    name minute second     id
##   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
## 1  John     68     37   8028
## 2 Steve     69      4 132205
```